# Detection of leaf on unpredictable background

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, shadow, image-segmentation

A project I have been working about for some time is a unsupervised leaf segmentation. The leaves are captured on a white or colored paper, and some of them has shadows.

I want to be able to threshold the leaf and also remove the shadow (while reserving the leaf's details); however I cannot use fixed threshold values due to diseases changing the color of the leaf.

Then, I begin to research and find out a proposal by Horprasert et. al. (1999) in "A Statistical Approach for Real-time Robust Background Subtraction and Shadow Detection", which compare areas in the image with colour of the now-known background using the chromacity distortion measure. This measure takes account of the fact that for desaturated colours, hue is not a relevant measure.

Based on it, I was able to achieve the following results:

[image: Example 01]

However, the leaves that are captured on a white paper need to change the Mask V cv2.bitwise_not() giving me the below result:

[image: Example 02]

I'm thinking that I'm forgetting some step to get a complete mask that will work for all or most of my leaves. Samples can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcDx.jpg).

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

def brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
    return np.sum(I*mu/sigma**2, axis=-1) / np.sum((mu/sigma)**2, axis=-1)


def chromacity_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
    alpha = brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma)[...,None]
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(((I - alpha * mu)/sigma)**2, axis=-1))

def bwareafilt ( image ):
    image = image.astype(np.uint8)
    nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)
    sizes = stats[:, -1]

    max_label = 1
    max_size = sizes[1]
    for i in range(2, nb_components):
        if sizes[i] > max_size:
            max_label = i
            max_size = sizes[i]

    img2 = np.zeros(output.shape)
    img2[output == max_label] = 255

    return img2

img = cv2.imread("Amostra03.jpeg")
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]
val = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]
sat = cv2.medianBlur(sat, 11)
val = cv2.medianBlur(val, 11)
thresh_S = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(sat , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
thresh_V = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(val , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);

mean_S, stdev_S = cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask = 255 - thresh_S)
mean_S = mean_S.ravel().flatten()
stdev_S = stdev_S.ravel()
chrom_S = chromacity_distortion(img, mean_S, stdev_S)
chrom255_S = cv2.normalize(chrom_S, chrom_S, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)[:,:,None]

mean_V, stdev_V = cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask = 255 - thresh_V)
mean_V = mean_V.ravel().flatten()
stdev_V = stdev_V.ravel()
chrom_V = chromacity_distortion(img, mean_V, stdev_V)
chrom255_V = cv2.normalize(chrom_V, chrom_V, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)[:,:,None]

thresh2_S = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(chrom255_S , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
thresh2_V = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(chrom255_V , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);

images = [img, thresh_S, thresh_V, cv2.bitwise_and(thresh2_S, cv2.bitwise_not(thresh2_V))]
titles = ['Original Image', 'Mask S', 'Mask V', 'S + V']
for i in range(4):
    plot.subplot(2,2,i+1),
    if i == 0 :
        plot.imshow(images[i])
    else :
        plot.imshow(images[i], cmap='gray')
    plot.title(titles[i])
    plot.xticks([]),plot.yticks([])
plot.show()
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: But what exactly is the "issue"? I can't see any clear qualitative difference between your first and second pictures. Also, simple thresholding on hue gives way, way better results for your samples than what is shown. (Also you should convert BGR to RGB before visualizing OpenCV images with pyplot.)

Comment: @Headcrab the S + V Mask are different when use cv2.bitwise_not()

Comment: @Headcrab The issue is to get a mask that avoid shadow

Comment: To avoid shadows (or at least minimize their influence) you can work with HSV, Lab or Luv color spaces. Additionally, you might want to try [SLIC](https://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels), although, this might not be the "unsupervised" solution you are looking for.

Comment: @RickM. I am working in HSV color space

Answer (score 5):

Try this on...I'm using "grabCut" from the openCV lib.  It's not perfect, but it might be a good start.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
#%matplotlib inline #uncomment if in notebook

def mask_leaf(im_name, external_mask=None):

    im = cv2.imread(im_name)
    im = cv2.blur(im, (5,5))

    height, width = im.shape[:2]

    mask = np.ones(im.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8) * 2 #start all possible background
    '''
    #from docs:
    0 GC_BGD defines an obvious background pixels.
    1 GC_FGD defines an obvious foreground (object) pixel.
    2 GC_PR_BGD defines a possible background pixel.
    3 GC_PR_FGD defines a possible foreground pixel.
    '''

    #2 circles are "drawn" on mask. a smaller centered one I assume all pixels are definite foreground. a bigger circle, probably foreground.
    r = 100
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(width/2.), int(height/2.)), 2*r, 3, -3) #possible fg
    #next 2 are greens...dark and bright to increase the number of fg pixels.
    mask[(im[:,:,0] < 45) & (im[:,:,1] > 55) & (im[:,:,2] < 55)] = 1  #dark green
    mask[(im[:,:,0] < 190) & (im[:,:,1] > 190) & (im[:,:,2] < 200)] = 1  #bright green
    mask[(im[:,:,0] > 200) & (im[:,:,1] > 200) & (im[:,:,2] > 200) & (mask != 1)] = 0 #pretty white

    cv2.circle(mask, (int(width/2.), int(height/2.)), r, 1, -3) #fg

    #if you pass in an external mask derived from some other operation it is factored in here.
    if external_mask is not None:
        mask[external_mask == 1] = 1

    bgdmodel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
    fgdmodel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
    cv2.grabCut(im, mask, None, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 1, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

    #show mask
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(mask)
    plt.show()

    #mask image
    mask2 = np.where((mask==1) + (mask==3), 255, 0).astype('uint8')
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask=mask2)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(output)
    plt.show()

mask_leaf('leaf1.jpg', external_mask=None)
mask_leaf('leaf2.jpg', external_mask=None)
```

[image: mask1]
[image: masked leaf 1]
[image: mask2]
[image: masked leaf2]

Addressing the external mask.  Here's an example of HDBSCAN clustering...I'm not going to go into the details...you can look up the docs and change it or use as-is.

```
import hdbscan
from collections import Counter


def hdbscan_mask(im_name):

    im = cv2.imread(im_name)
    im = cv2.blur(im, (5,5))

    indices = np.dstack(np.indices(im.shape[:2]))
    data = np.concatenate((indices, im), axis=-1)
    data = data[:,2:]

    data = imb.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], 3)
    clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=1000, min_samples=20)
    clusterer.fit(data)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(clusterer.labels_.reshape(im.shape[0:2]))
    plt.show()

    height, width = im.shape[:2]

    mask = np.ones(im.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8) * 2 #start all possible background
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(width/2.), int(height/2.)), 100, 1, -3) #possible fg

    #grab cluster number for circle
    vals_im = clusterer.labels_.reshape(im.shape[0:2])

    vals = vals_im[mask == 1]
    commonvals = []
    cnts = Counter(vals)
    for v, count in cnts.most_common(20):
    #print '%i: %7d' % (v, count)
    if v == -1:
        continue
    commonvals.append(v)

    tst = np.in1d(vals_im, np.array(commonvals))
    tst = tst.reshape(vals_im.shape)

    hmask = tst.astype(np.uint8)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(hmask)
    plt.show()

    return hmask

hmask = hdbscan_mask('leaf1.jpg')
```

[image: hdbscan cluster labels]
[image: hdbscan leaf mask]

then to use the initial function with the new mask (output suppressed):

```
mask_leaf('leaf1.jpg', external_mask=hmask)
```

This was all made in a notebook from scratch so hopefully there's no errant variables that choke it up when running it somewhere else.  (note: I did NOT swap BGR to RGB for plt display, sorry)

Comment: it works for most of my cases, but as I said some of my samples get a coloration due to disease which messed up with the fixed values.

Comment: well, you can only get so much from stackoverflow!  if you want more, you can hire someone.

Comment: Nice answer! It can take so much effort to write an answer like this; it's a shame when some askers don't think that's enough.